# Sum of calculated measure column to be used in other measure

Tags: database, powerbi, dax, measure

I currently have a table constructed from a database *Port* like so, which shows the amount of people in a region (A,B,C,D), how many people there are in that region and how many miles they have run:

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9NDV.png)

Now, the column *Total_Amount_Of_Miles* is made by a measure based on the sum of miles people have run, filtered by region). I used the following code for this:

```
INT(SUMX( DISTINCT(Port[People]),CALCULATE(SUM(Port[Miles_Run]))/CALCULATE(COUNT(Port[People]))))
```

I was wondering if there is a way to use the total of *Total_Amount_Of_Miles* in another measure, which I then use to calculate the percentage of the total?

The resulting table would look like this:

[Resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMSRt.png)

I tried to create the measure as follows:

```
Total_Share = [Total_Amount_Of_Miles]/SUM([Total_Amount_Of_Miles])
```

But this gives an error as you cannot sum a measure, given that it is context-dependent.

Would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this measure instead:

```
Total share = 
DIVIDE( 
    [Total Amount of miles], 
    CALCULATE(
        [Total Amount of miles], 
        ALL('Table')
    )
)
```

[image]